# Issues after updating Cordova from 3 to 2 on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

After updating my Visual Studio 2015 Professional to use Cordova Update 3, I became unable to use it. New and existing Cordova projects don't show my www folder's files (although they still exist in disk) and I can't add them back due the error "The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file _apachecordovaprojectsourceitems.targets".

Every build fails with error MSB4044 The "RunMdaInstall" task was not given a value for the required parameter "MdaVsixDir".

There's a bug opened for this issue https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1894979/cordova-update-3-totally-breaks-project-type

However, I have another machine where the VS 2015 still have the Cordova Update 2 installed and everything is ok. I don't dare to click the update button... The problem is that I can't use this machine to develop my project because it belongs to the company I work for, and I only work on this Cordova project at night, at home.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a fix for this bug, thanks to help from MS Support!

1) Delete this folder: C:\Users[username]\appdata\local\microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

2) Open Visual Studio and create a new blank cordova project. This will regenerate the deleted folder.

3) Debug the blank project in ripple, first run may complain about a problem with Chrome and the debugger may fail to connect. Close chrome after this, and try debugging one more time and it should connect as desired.

4) Enjoy a once-more functioning development environment!